# How to use typedef variables to functions as arguments

Tags: c, function, pointers, malloc, typedef

```
typedef struct {
    int age, height, weight;
} Person;
//this is in global variables

...

Person *p = (Person *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 20); //this is local variable in main function
```

In this situation, I want to make functions that use typedef variables as arguments.

For example,
if I make a function like `void print_line()` that print age, height, weight , what should I write in `()`?
At first I wrote `void print_line(Person);` But VS says it's an error.

Please help me.

Comment: `typedef` defines a "shortcut" to an existing type, it doesn't define a variable. `Person` is a type, not a variable

Comment: How about `void print_line(Person *p)`?

Comment: Thank you. I wrote `void print_line(Person *p) and it works.

Comment: The `malloc()` line in your example looks dangerous.  You should use `sizeof` to get the size of the `Person` type rather than trying to figure out how many `int` worth of space you need for one, eg. `malloc(sizeof(Person) * 5)` for 5 of them.

Comment: Also see [c - Do I cast the result of malloc? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: I don't  get it. Is the size of Person decided with `N` and `sizeof(int)`?

Comment: @RiRiHui See my answer

Answer (score 2):

> How to use typedef variables to functions as arguments

**Just like you use the build-in types.**

That's the whole idea behind `typedef` - you create your own type and use it like any other type.

If you want to pass an `int` you do

```
void foo(int input) {...}
```

If you want to pass you own type you do

```
typedef ...... myType;

void foo(myType input) {...}
```

**Off topic**:

Your code:

```
Person *p=(Person*)malloc(sizeof(int)*20);
```

is wrong! Don't use `sizeof(int)` as your type `Person` doesn't have that size. Less important - but still - in C you don't cast `malloc`. The way to do it is:

```
    Person *p=malloc(20 * sizeof *p);  // Allocate memory for 20 Person
```

or

```
    Person *p=malloc(20 * sizeof(Person));   // Allocate memory for 20 Person
```

But the first is to be preferred.

Comment: Thank you! Now I got it! You such a genius!

Comment: @RiRiHui Genius... well - no I'm not - I've just spend quite some time programming C